# Debug Windows Phone 8.1 app built with Phonegap build

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

We have an enterprise app which targets ios, android and windows phone 8.1 devices.

It is built using SAP-based development tools and exported to the phonegap build https://build.phonegap.com

This results in an .xap app binary that we can install using the AppDeploy.exe from the SDK.

However, we are not able to debug or view console.log messages for this app.
(For Android we're able to debug through chrome.
For iOS, we're able to debug through safari)

Are there any possibilities of connecting a debugger to an .xap which has been built outside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, VS doesn't support connecting the VS debugger to an XAP created outside VS, but you may try deploying it to IIS server and see if that works as mentioned in http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-debug-silverlight-application-with-only-xap-file